# ¿ como obtener datos del lado del cliente con sockets ?

Tags: nodejs, angular, socket.io

Trabajo con sockets actualmente, de la siguiente manera, tengo un gps que esta apuntando hacia mi servidor, de momento tuve que hacer que mi ip sea publica y le asigne un puerto donde llegaran los datos:
Ahora del lado del servidor con nodejs tengo esto:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
//const net = require('net');
const port = 2345;
const host = '192.168.15.12';
var server = app.listen(port, host);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
app.use((req,res,next) =>{
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin',"http://localhost:4200/");
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials',"true");
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers',"Origin, X-Requested-With, 
Content-Type, Accept");
next();
})
//const server = net.createServer();
server.listen(port, host, () => {
console.log(' Servidor corriendo en port ' + port + '.');
});

let sockets = [];

server.on('connection', function(sock) {
console.log('CONNECTADO: ' + sock.remoteAddress + ':' + sock.remotePort);
sockets.push(sock);

sock.on('data', function(data) {
    data = String(data);
    console.log(typeof(data));
    console.log('DATA ' + sock.remoteAddress + ': ' + data);

    if(typeof(data) != "string" ){
        console.log("Error 1");
    }
    if(data.length < 19){
        console.log("Error 2");
    }
    if(data[0] != '(' && data[data.length-1] != ')'){
        console.log("Error 3");
    }
    else{

        var ID    = data.substr(1,1+11);
        var Comando = data.substr(13,4);
        console.log("ID: "+ID);
        console.log("Comando: "+Comando);
        io.on('connection',(socket) =>{
            socket.emit('data',{
                id:ID,
                comando:Comando
            });
        });

        if(Comando == "BR00"){

            //Fecha
            var offset = 17;
            var offset_end = 6;
            var date = data.substr(offset,offset_end);
            console.log("Fecha: "+date);

            //Disponibilidad
            offset = 23;
            offset_end =  1;
            var disponibilidad = data.substr(offset,offset_end);
            console.log("Dispo: "+disponibilidad);

            //Latitud
            offset = 24;
            offset_end = 9;
            var lat = data.substr(offset,offset_end);
            console.log("Latitud: "+lat);

            //Indicador de latitud
            offset = 33;
            offset_end = 1;
            var lat_in = data.substr(offset,offset_end);
            console.log("Indicador lat: "+lat_in);

            //Longitud
            offset = 34;
            offset_end = 10;
            var lng = data.substr(offset,offset_end);
            console.log("Longitud: "+lng);

            //Indicador de longitud
            offset = 44;
            offset_end = 1;
            var lng_in = data.substr(offset,offset_end);
            console.log("Indicador lng: "+lng_in);

            //Velocidad
            offset = 45;
            offset_end = 5;
            var Velocidad = data.substr(offset,offset_end);
            console.log("Velocidad: "+Velocidad);

            //Hora
            offset = 50;
            offset_end = 6;
            var hora = data.substr(offset,offset_end);
            console.log("Hora: "+hora);

            if(disponibilidad = "A"){
                var lat_dd = parseFloat(lat.substr(0,2)) + 
   parseFloat(lat.substr(2,9)) / 60;
                if(lat_in != "N"){
                    lat_dd = - lat_dd;
                }
                var lng_dd = parseFloat(lng.substr(0,3)) + 
               parseFloat(lng.substr(3,10)) / 60;
                if(lat_in != "E"){
                    lng_dd = - lng_dd;
                }

                console.log("Lat: "+lat_dd);
                console.log("Lon: "+lng_dd);

            }
        }

    }

    // Write the data back to all the connected, the client will receive it 
   as data from the server
    sockets.forEach(function(sock, index, array) {
        sock.write(sock.remoteAddress + ':' + sock.remotePort + " said " + 
  data + '\n');
    });
});

// Add a 'close' event handler to this instance of socket
sock.on('close', function(data) {
    let index = sockets.findIndex(function(o) {
        return o.remoteAddress === sock.remoteAddress && o.remotePort === sock.remotePort;
    })
    if (index !== -1) sockets.splice(index, 1);
    console.log('CLOSED: ' + sock.remoteAddress + ' ' + sock.remotePort);
});
```

});

Este servidor cuanto le ejecuto me devuelve datos del gps en consola, Ahora del lado del cliente con Angular version 6 utilizo el siguiente codigo,

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
data: any;
messageText: string;
constructor() {
// this.socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');
// this.socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
}

ngOnInit() {
const socket = io('192.168.15.1:2345');
    socket.on('connect', (data) => {
      console.log(data);
    } );
  }
}
```

y correctamente si me devuelve datos, pero en consola me vienen muchos errores, como lo muestro en la siguiente [image: datosdevueltos]:

Ahora bien soy nuevo trabajando con sockets, lo que estoy haciendo es correcto ?, es la correcta funcion de implementancion del lado del client ? cualquier observacion me seria de mucha ayuda.